# Karma Start Chrome failed 2 time

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

When I run  `Karma Start` to run my unit tests for an Angular 4 App I get this error:

```
Chrome have not captures in 60000 ms, killing

Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).

Chrome have not captures in 60000 ms, killing

Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).

Chrome failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
```

This is my karma.conf.js file

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeNoSandbox: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    singleRun: false,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000
  });
};
```

After researching it seems like it might be a compatibility issue with the version of Chrome being used. I've tried adding the --no-sandbox flag to the karma config file but it still doesn't work. Is anyone out there having the same issue or have had this issue before? Not sure what my next step should be.

Right after I run `Karma start`, a new Chrome browser window opens but it stays on a blank screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Z.Bagley I'm new to angular and I don't really know what type of info I should provide for my issue(which config files). I thought this error message was is specific enough. Thanks for the downvote though. Sorry If my post was too general.

Comment: Try `chrome`. Also, make sure you have updated webdriver.

Comment: There are nearly a billion possible problems that cause this, from the top to bottom of the entire project. First step is to use `ng new` to generate a brand new project to see if the error exists. If it does, try other browsers.

Comment: @torazaburo what is webdriver? Would that be a dependency?

Comment: You should have an npm rule such as `webdriver-manager update` or something. By the way, does Chrome come up?

Comment: same problem here. Did you solve it?